# loading data to hive table using file in local file system

Tags: hive

While loading file to hive table it's giving "unable to move source file" .I'm using cloudera virtual box.
Attaching scrrenshot of error , file which I'm uploading and hive table schema

[image]

2)

[image]

3)

[image]

Comment: Please use text, not screen shots. Have you tried using `hdfs -put` instead, and maybe an external Hive table?

Comment: Actually I created another virtual box with the same code it worked